# react-query doesn't stop retrying to fetch an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I want to implement this scenario by `react-query`:

My component gets an API and should try once when the client's internet was disconnected and never re-fetch if internet was reconnected... and after 3 seconds if retry was not successful, should show an error with a button for retrying the request.

```
const URL = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&inc=name';

const Example = () => {
  const { error, data, isLoading, refetch } = useQuery('test', () =>
    fetch(URL).then(response => response.json()).then(data => data.results), {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    refetchOnReconnect: false,
    retry: 1,
    retryDelay: 3000
  });

  if (isLoading) return <span>Loading...</span>

  if (error) return <span>Error: {error.message} <button onClick={refetch}>retry</button></span>

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Length: {data ? console.log(data.length) : null}</h1>
      <button onClick={refetch}>Refetch</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

As considering the above code, I set `refetchOnReconnect: false` to disable the refetch after internet was connected, `retry: 1` to set once try and `retryDelay: 3000` to set a limit for retrying time.

But when I use Throttling -> offline in DevTools, after clicking on button just shows the last result and doesn't show error and retry button after 3 seconds...

So, is there any way to I handle this feature?

Answer (score 2):

`React-query` is using the data in the cache, you should invalidate the query to fetch the data again by calling the function `invalidateQueries`:

```
onst URL = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&inc=name'

const Example = () => {
  // Get QueryClient from the context
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  const { error, data, isLoading, refetch } = useQuery(
    'test',
    () =>
      fetch(URL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => data.results),
    {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      refetchOnReconnect: false,
      retry: 1,
      retryDelay: 3000
    }
  )

  const buttonClickHandler = () => queryClient.invalidateQueries('test') // <=== invalidate the cache

  if (isLoading) return <span>Loading...</span>

  if (error)
    return (
      <span>
        Error: {error.message} <button onClick={refetch}>retry</button>
      </span>
    )

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Length: {data ? console.log(data.length) : null}</h1>
      <button onClick={buttonClickHandler}>Refetch</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: but with this scenario, i have to import queryClient for each pages... i think it's not the best practice and this package should handle this issue internally

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should check staleTime or cacheTime logic. As far as I understood your problem, you are getting old data because react query doesnt know if this data new or old. Use `staleTime:0` to get exactly what you want.